# Starting java jar or even "java -version" stuck in Mac OS X. Cannot attach to debug

Tags: java, debugging

I've encountered a problem which may or may not be related to the programming directly but sure related to the debugging. So I decided to put it here. I may be wrong and kindly asking to understand the reason.

For Mac OS X 10.13.x and Java 8 Oracle JDK I have this problem:

- Periodically and rather frequently last few days I cannot start any java applet or even run "java -version' as the process stuck at the very beginning.
- I can see the PID of the newly created process and CPU time is always zero. I cannot attach to debug the PID and therefore cannot understand what holds the process.
- No debugger or 'jconsole' I tried can attach.
- If I kill all other java processes the situation persists.
- Only rebooting the Mac OS X allows running java processes again.

I'd be grateful to see any comments.

Comment: Looks like an OS problem, did you already try on Superuser?

Comment: I don't remember if tried under root. Will do next time. 
If this is the OS problem why java only? Apple hates Oracle?